# iOS-style callouts in Android Maps API?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, callouts

I'm porting an iOS app to Android. The iOS app uses MapKit; the Android app uses corresponding Google Maps API. In the Android API I can't find any functionality analogous to iOS's callout bubble ([canShowCallout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/canShowCallout)). I've implemented my own simple layout with text and a button, but it doesn't look great, and recently I've stumbled across an Android app which clearly uses the iOS graphics. Are they hacking or using something legit that, after a day of searching, I can't find?

Thanks,

MapMaker

Comment: It is not a good idea to mimic appearance of one OS inside the another. The application must look and feel a part of the device. That is, on iPhone it must look in iPhone way, on Android - in Android way, and on Windows Phone 7 - in Windows Phone 7 way. When porting the application you must preserve the functionality but adopt the native look&feel of target platform. All guidelines of all platforms are agree on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean those popup balloons that appear after a tap on a marker? There is an implementation of that for Android [here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

Comment: Kevin, that's what I'm looking for, yes, just closer in look to what Google provides on iOS. I had come up with something along the lines of the code you indicated, but that code also answers other questions I had... thanks!